# recursion: determining limiting condition

Tags: java, recursion

I have an incomplete handout about recursion and one of the example question asks what is the "limiting condition" of this particular recursive method:

```
public static int fib(int a, int b, int n){
if(n==1)
     return a;
else if(n==2)
     return b;
else
     return fib(a,b,n-1) + fib(a,b,n-2);
}
```

the choices are:

1. n>=0
2. a>=1
3. b>=1
4. n>=1

if "limiting condition" refers to when this method is valid, I guess that answer is n>=1 ?

Comment: what is your question here??

Comment: So what are you asking???

Comment: what is the limiting condition of this recursive method?

Comment: Well, I don't think that StackOverflow is a platform for doing your homework :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

Note that if `n <1` in each iteration you will decrease `n`by 1 (or 2) and never<sup>1</sup> reach the stop condition, which is greater than `n`. This will cause an infinite loop in theory, or a stack overflow in practice.

The method provided assumes that `n>1` to function properly, in some places this is called a precondition to the method.

---

(1) Ignoring integer overflow here....

Comment: this limiting condition was not defined well on my handout, thanks for verifying!